# Resolving env inside another env

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, kubernetes

So i would like to print my env variable which contains other variables.
For example i have:

```
MY_VARS="My var are:\nVAR1 = ${MY_VAR1}\nVAR2 = ${MY_VAR2}"
MY_VAR1=var1
MY_VAR2=var2
```

and i would like to make it possible in way like:

```
printf "${MY_VARS}" > my.conf
```

or

```
printf "$(echo ${MY_VARS})" > my.conf
```

to get sth like in `my.conf` file:

```
My var are:
VAR1 = var1
VAR2 = var2
```

but it dosent work.
Is ther possibility to do such thing ?
I need it to us it with Kubernetes so i can set env in my ReplicationController and use it with Kubernetes envs like `SERVICE_HOST` and `SERVICE_PORT`
There is another problem that Kubernetes is changing my `MY_VARS` variable to multiline inside container so it looks like:

```
MY_VARS=My var are:
VAR1 = ${MY_VAR1}
VAR2 = ${MY_VAR2}
```

Hope it's quite clear :)

### My solution:

```
while read -r line
do
  printf "$line\n" >> conf.tmp
done <<< "$CONFIG"

while read -r line
do
  eval echo $line >> conf
done < conf.tmp
```

Where `CONFIG` variable is passed by me to the container and this variable contains Kubernetes service variables with IPs and Ports.
I had to make it twice because `eval` couldnt resolve `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

With bash you can perform [indirect references](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html) but it would not replace the value of your variable directly, only when you use it from a bash terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to define the vars first.  The following script prints out what you want:

```
MY_VAR1=var1
MY_VAR2=var2
MY_VARS="My var are:\nVAR1 = ${MY_VAR1}\nVAR2 = ${MY_VAR2}"
printf "${MY_VARS}"
```